# Mostrar apenas 1 categoria na página

Tags: php, wordpress

Preciso criar 2 funções, cada uma irá mostrar uma categoria (comercial e residencial)

```
    <?php

class MP_Emmet_Plugin_Portfolio {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'mp_emmet_section_portfolio', array( $this, 'get_html' ) );
    }

    /*
     * Get default portfolio
     */

    public function get_default_portfolio() {
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation = esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_animation', 'fadeInLeft' ) );
        ?>
        <div class="portfolio-list">
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio1.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Logotypes', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio2.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Web-design', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio3.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Print', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio4.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Aplications', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio5.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Aplications', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio6.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'llustrations', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio7.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Web-design', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
            if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
            endif;
            ?>">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-content">
                    <img src="<?php echo MP_EMMET_PLUGIN_PATH . 'images/portfolio8.jpg'; ?>"
                         class="attachment-thumb-portfolio wp-post-image"
                         alt="<?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?>">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <div>
                                <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php _e( 'Fitsy logo', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h5>
                                <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                    <span><?php _e( 'Your category', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /*
     * Get portfolio
     */

    public function get_portfolio() {
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation = esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_animation', 'fadeInLeft' ) );
        $posts_per_page               = apply_filters( 'mp_emmet_portfolio_posts_per_page', 8 );
        $args                         = array(
            'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page
        );
        $prizes                       = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $prizes->have_posts() ) {
            ?>
            <div class="portfolio-list ">
                <?php
                while ( $prizes->have_posts() ) {
                    $prizes->the_post();
                    ?>
                    <div class="portfolio-box  <?php
                    if ( $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation != 'none' ): echo 'animated anHidden"  data-animation="' . $mp_emmet_portfolio_animation;
                    endif;
                    ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="portfolio-content">
                            <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail( 'mp-emmet-thumb-medium' );
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <div class="portfolio-empty-thumbnail">
                                    <span class="date-post">
                                        <?php echo get_post_time( 'j M' ); ?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                <div class="hover-content">
                                    <div>
                                        <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                                        <?php
                                        $post_categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_tag' );
                                        if ( ! empty( $post_categories ) ) :
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="portfolio-categories">
                                                <?php
                                                $last_key = count( $post_categories );
                                                $i        = 0;
                                                foreach ( $post_categories as $cat ) {
                                                    echo '<span>' . $cat->name . '</span>';
                                                    if ( ++ $i != $last_key ) {
                                                        echo '<span>,</span> ';
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                        endif;
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php }
                ?>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {
            $this->get_default_portfolio();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Get title
     */

    public function get_title() {
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_title = esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_title' ) );
        if ( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_title', false ) === false ) :
            ?>
            <h2 class="section-title"><?php _e( 'our portfolio', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></h2>
            <?php
        else:
            if ( ! empty( $mp_emmet_portfolio_title ) ):
                ?>
                <h2 class="section-title"><?php echo $mp_emmet_portfolio_title; ?></h2>
                <?php
            endif;
        endif;
    }

    /*
     * Get description
     */

    public function get_description() {
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_description = wp_kses( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_description' ), mp_emmet_plugin_allowed_html() );

        if ( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_description', false ) === false ) :
            ?>
            <div
                class="section-description"><?php _e( 'In the portfolio section you can display your works consisting of screenshots and additional information', 'mp-emmet' ); ?></div>
            <?php
        else:
            if ( ! empty( $mp_emmet_portfolio_description ) ):
                ?>
                <div class="section-description"><?php echo $mp_emmet_portfolio_description; ?></div>
                <?php
            endif;
        endif;
    }

    /*
     * Get Buttons
     */

    public function get_buttons() {
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_label = esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_button_label', __( 'check all works', 'mp-emmet' ) ) );
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_url   = esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_button_url', '#portfolio' ) );
        ?>
        <div class="section-buttons">
            <?php
            if ( ! empty( $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_label ) && ! empty( $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_url ) ):
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_url; ?>"
                   title="<?php echo $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_label; ?>" class="button white-button">
                    <?php echo $mp_emmet_portfolio_button_label; ?></a>
                <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /*
     * features section html
     */

    public function get_html() {
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_id_option = esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_id' ) );
        $mp_emmet_portfolio_id        = empty( $mp_emmet_portfolio_id_option ) ? 'portfolio' : esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'theme_portfolio_id' ) );
        ?>
        <section id="<?php echo $mp_emmet_portfolio_id; ?>" class="portfolio-section white-section default-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section-content">
                    <?php
                    $this->get_title();
                    $this->get_description();
                    $this->get_portfolio();
                    $this->get_buttons();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: você está usando páginas pra mostrar categorias?

Comment: Isso, criei 2 templates de páginas do wordpress, cada uma para mostrar uma categoria.

Comment: Neste código está mostrando certo query_posts(array('portfolio_category' => 'comercial', 'posts_per_page' => 0)));

Comment: Nesse filtro vc tá querendo somente os posts que tenham **SÓ** a categoria 'comercial', é isso?

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo isso

Answer (score 2):

Não é preciso usar páginas nem [`query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) pra isso*. Use a [Hierarquia de Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) do WordPress.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você deve ter um arquivo genérico de listas tipo `archive.php`, ou mesmo o `index.php`. Crie uma cópia dele e renomeie como `taxonomy-portfolio_category.php`.

Pronto, ele vai ser carregado quando vc estiver listando qualquer termo na taxonomia `portfolio_category`. Se precisar de um template somente para o termo `comercial`, use `taxonomy-portfolio_category-comercial.php`

Comment: No caso, eu poderia estar usando o link que o wordpress gera para guardar os posts de cada categoria ( www.meusite.com.br/portofolio-category/comercial ). O problema é que estou usando uma seção do tema que trás esses posts (  if (has_action('mp_emmet_section_portfolio')) {
    do_action('mp_emmet_section_portfolio');
} ) . Ou seja, não estou usando a abse do archive.php para mostrar e sim a seção do site. Eu criei um template com essa seção, agora só falta separar pelas categorias.

Comment: Eu copiei o template da página que fiz , usando a seção do site e coloquei o nome taxonomy-portfolio_category-comercial.php. Ele está pegando os títulos dos posts e mostrando no título da página. Vou colocar o código todo na edição do post aqui.